# how to use textures in android ndk with opengl es 2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk

I tried to the code from [Fastest 2D frame rate possible with android NDK, my try included, better options available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878536/fastest-2d-frame-rate-possible-with-android-ndk-my-try-included-better-options/3476199#3476199) ,
but textures didn't show, just filled with black.

who can show me a example of how to use textures in android ndk with opengl es 2.0?

Thanks!

my phone is Moto Milestone with android 2.1.